# How to access element of a VectorUDT column in a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a dataframe `df` with a `VectorUDT` column named `features`. How do I get an element of the column, say first element?

I've tried doing the following

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
first_elem_udf = udf(lambda row: row.values[0])
df.select(first_elem_udf(df.features)).show()
```

but I get a `net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict(for numpy.dtype)` error. Same error if I do `first_elem_udf = first_elem_udf(lambda row: row.toArray()[0])` instead.

I also tried `explode()` but I get an error because it requires an array or map type.

This should be a common operation, I think.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Convert output to `float`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, udf

def ith_(v, i):
    try:
        return float(v[i])
    except ValueError:
        return None

ith = udf(ith_, DoubleType())
```

Example usage:

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, Vectors.dense([1, 2, 3])),
    (2, Vectors.sparse(3, [1], [9]))
]).toDF(["id", "features"])

df.select(ith("features", lit(1))).show()

## +-----------------+
## |ith_(features, 1)|
## +-----------------+
## |              2.0|
## |              9.0|
## +-----------------+
```

Explanation:

Output values have to be reserialized to equivalent Java objects. If you want to access `values` (beware of `SparseVectors`) you should use `item` method:

```py
v.values.item(0)
```

which return standard Python scalars. Similarly if you want to access all values as a dense structure:

```
v.toArray().tolist()
```

Comment: I get `Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)`. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer using spark.sql, you can use the follow custom function 'to_array' to convert the vector to array. Then you can manipulate it as an array.

```
 from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType
 def to_array_(v):
        return v.toArray().tolist()
 from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
 sqlContext=SQLContext(spark.sparkContext, sparkSession=spark, jsqlContext=None) 
 sqlContext.udf.register("to_array",to_array_,  ArrayType(DoubleType()))
```

### example

```
    from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
    
    df = sc.parallelize([
        (1, Vectors.dense([1, 2, 3])),
        (2, Vectors.sparse(3, [1], [9]))
    ]).toDF(["id", "features"])
    
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("tb")
    
    spark.sql("""select * , to_array(features)[1] Second from  tb   """).toPandas()
```

### output

```
    id  features    Second
0   1   [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] 2.0
1   2   (0.0, 9.0, 0.0) 9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem with not being able to use explode(). One thing you can do is use [VectorSlice](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) from the pyspark.ml.feature library. Like so:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorSlicer
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

slicer = VectorSlicer(inputCol="features", outputCol="features_one", indices=[0])

output = slicer.transform(df)

output.select("features", "features_one").show()
```

Comment: I like this solution best, but it still results in the "features_one" column being a 1-element list.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any quick way to extract the 1 element out? 
Also can we write pipeline to "explode" multiple elements from the veactor?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to split the probability columns generated after training a PySpark ML model into usable columns. This does not use UDF or numpy. And this will only work for binary classification. Here lr_pred is the dataframe which has the predictions from the Logistic Regression Model.

```
prob_df1=lr_pred.withColumn("probability",lr_pred["probability"].cast("String"))

prob_df =prob_df1.withColumn('probabilityre',split(regexp_replace("probability", "^\[|\]", ""), ",")[1].cast(DoubleType()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 3.0.0 this can be done without using UDF.

```
from pyspark.ml.functions import vector_to_array
```

https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark/

Why is `Vector[Double]` is used in the results? That's not a very nice data type.

Comment: Please refrain from using profanity.