# Access element of a vector in a Spark DataFrame without using UDF in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I`m trying to solve exactly this problem:
[[Access element of a vector in a Spark DataFrame (Logistic Regression probability vector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425159/access-element-of-a-vector-in-a-spark-dataframe-logistic-regression-probability][1])
  **but without using UDF in Pyspark**

I see lot of options in Scala but nothing for Pyspark.

Comment: dense vector or sparse vector?

Comment: Hi @Reema, Have you checked my answer? if it is working please upvote + accept.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have predictions dataframe as below-

```
predictions.show(false)
```

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------+
|label      |features                              |indexedLabel|indexedFeatures                       |rawPrediction                                             |probability                                                  |prediction|predictedLabel |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------+
|Iris-setosa|(123,[0,37,82,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[0,37,82,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[7.094347002635046,1.7433876811594202,1.1622653162055336] |[0.7094347002635046,0.174338768115942,0.11622653162055337]   |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[0,39,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[0,39,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[7.867074275362319,1.2433876811594202,0.8895380434782609] |[0.7867074275362319,0.12433876811594202,0.0889538043478261]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[0,39,62,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[0,39,62,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[5.159492704509035,2.794443583750028,2.046063711740936]   |[0.5159492704509036,0.2794443583750028,0.2046063711740936]   |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[2,39,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[2,39,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[7.822379507920459,1.2164981462756994,0.9611223458038423] |[0.7822379507920459,0.12164981462756994,0.09611223458038423] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[2,43,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[2,43,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[7.049652235193186,1.7164981462756992,1.233849618531115]  |[0.7049652235193186,0.17164981462756992,0.1233849618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[2,48,58,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[2,48,58,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[4.375677221716952,3.456351863073957,2.167970915209091]   |[0.4375677221716952,0.3456351863073957,0.21679709152090912]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[4,43,71,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[4,43,71,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[3.521332027976265,3.4847888973511556,2.9938790746725785] |[0.3521332027976265,0.34847888973511554,0.29938790746725785] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[4,54,58,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[4,54,58,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[3.6413022217169515,3.925101863073957,2.433595915209091]  |[0.36413022217169516,0.3925101863073957,0.2433595915209091]  |1.0       |Iris-versicolor|
|Iris-setosa|(123,[10,38,58,110],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[10,38,58,110],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[4.537038655825478,3.3499080646243447,2.1130532795501766] |[0.4537038655825478,0.33499080646243445,0.21130532795501766] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[12,48,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[12,48,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.315277235193186,2.185248146275699,1.499474618531115]   |[0.6315277235193186,0.21852481462756992,0.1499474618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[12,52,71,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[12,52,71,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[2.657695664339902,4.252970715532974,3.0893336201271238]  |[0.2657695664339902,0.4252970715532974,0.3089333620127124]   |1.0       |Iris-versicolor|
|Iris-setosa|(123,[13,38,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[13,38,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.315277235193186,2.185248146275699,1.499474618531115]   |[0.6315277235193186,0.21852481462756992,0.1499474618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[15,39,59,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[15,39,59,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[9.434782608695652,0.391304347826087,0.17391304347826086] |[0.9434782608695651,0.03913043478260869,0.017391304347826084]|0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[17,37,59,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[17,37,59,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[8.662055335968379,0.8913043478260869,0.44664031620553357]|[0.866205533596838,0.08913043478260871,0.044664031620553366] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[17,39,59,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[17,39,59,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.818110128751459,1.6741784322348767,1.5077114390136637] |[0.681811012875146,0.1674178432234877,0.1507711439013664]    |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[20,35,63,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[20,35,63,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[8.393939393939394,0.8833333333333333,0.7227272727272727] |[0.8393939393939395,0.08833333333333333,0.07227272727272727] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[25,37,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[25,37,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.315277235193186,2.185248146275699,1.499474618531115]   |[0.6315277235193186,0.21852481462756992,0.1499474618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[27,47,63,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[27,47,63,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[4.916336653323167,2.646676038886771,2.4369873077900626]  |[0.4916336653323167,0.2646676038886771,0.24369873077900625]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[29,48,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[29,48,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.315277235193186,2.185248146275699,1.499474618531115]   |[0.6315277235193186,0.21852481462756992,0.1499474618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[33,35,96,110],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[33,35,96,110],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[2.6034320984484296,4.194443583750028,3.2021243178015424] |[0.26034320984484294,0.41944435837500277,0.32021243178015424]|1.0       |Iris-versicolor|
+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

please execute below query to fetch probability vector 
** PS : there are other programmatic method to fetch the probability vector, but this is the way i think without using udfs **

```
predictions.selectExpr("*", "get_json_object(to_json(struct(probability)), '$.probability.values[0]') as fetch_probability").show(false)
```

```
predictions.selectExpr("*", "get_json_object(to_json(struct(probability)), '$.probability.values[0]') as fetch_probability").show(false)
+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------+-------------------+
|label      |features                              |indexedLabel|indexedFeatures                       |rawPrediction                                             |probability                                                  |prediction|predictedLabel |fetch_probability  |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------+-------------------+
|Iris-setosa|(123,[0,37,82,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[0,37,82,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[7.094347002635046,1.7433876811594202,1.1622653162055336] |[0.7094347002635046,0.174338768115942,0.11622653162055337]   |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.7094347002635046 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[0,39,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[0,39,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[7.867074275362319,1.2433876811594202,0.8895380434782609] |[0.7867074275362319,0.12433876811594202,0.0889538043478261]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.7867074275362319 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[0,39,62,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[0,39,62,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[5.159492704509035,2.794443583750028,2.046063711740936]   |[0.5159492704509036,0.2794443583750028,0.2046063711740936]   |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.5159492704509036 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[2,39,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[2,39,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[7.822379507920459,1.2164981462756994,0.9611223458038423] |[0.7822379507920459,0.12164981462756994,0.09611223458038423] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.7822379507920459 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[2,43,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[2,43,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[7.049652235193186,1.7164981462756992,1.233849618531115]  |[0.7049652235193186,0.17164981462756992,0.1233849618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.7049652235193186 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[2,48,58,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[2,48,58,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[4.375677221716952,3.456351863073957,2.167970915209091]   |[0.4375677221716952,0.3456351863073957,0.21679709152090912]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.4375677221716952 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[4,43,71,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[4,43,71,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[3.521332027976265,3.4847888973511556,2.9938790746725785] |[0.3521332027976265,0.34847888973511554,0.29938790746725785] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.3521332027976265 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[4,54,58,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |0.0         |(123,[4,54,58,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]) |[3.6413022217169515,3.925101863073957,2.433595915209091]  |[0.36413022217169516,0.3925101863073957,0.2433595915209091]  |1.0       |Iris-versicolor|0.36413022217169516|
|Iris-setosa|(123,[10,38,58,110],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[10,38,58,110],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[4.537038655825478,3.3499080646243447,2.1130532795501766] |[0.4537038655825478,0.33499080646243445,0.21130532795501766] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.4537038655825478 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[12,48,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[12,48,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.315277235193186,2.185248146275699,1.499474618531115]   |[0.6315277235193186,0.21852481462756992,0.1499474618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.6315277235193186 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[12,52,71,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[12,52,71,107],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[2.657695664339902,4.252970715532974,3.0893336201271238]  |[0.2657695664339902,0.4252970715532974,0.3089333620127124]   |1.0       |Iris-versicolor|0.2657695664339902 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[13,38,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[13,38,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.315277235193186,2.185248146275699,1.499474618531115]   |[0.6315277235193186,0.21852481462756992,0.1499474618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.6315277235193186 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[15,39,59,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[15,39,59,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[9.434782608695652,0.391304347826087,0.17391304347826086] |[0.9434782608695651,0.03913043478260869,0.017391304347826084]|0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.9434782608695651 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[17,37,59,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[17,37,59,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[8.662055335968379,0.8913043478260869,0.44664031620553357]|[0.866205533596838,0.08913043478260871,0.044664031620553366] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.866205533596838  |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[17,39,59,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[17,39,59,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.818110128751459,1.6741784322348767,1.5077114390136637] |[0.681811012875146,0.1674178432234877,0.1507711439013664]    |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.681811012875146  |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[20,35,63,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[20,35,63,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[8.393939393939394,0.8833333333333333,0.7227272727272727] |[0.8393939393939395,0.08833333333333333,0.07227272727272727] |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.8393939393939395 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[25,37,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[25,37,62,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.315277235193186,2.185248146275699,1.499474618531115]   |[0.6315277235193186,0.21852481462756992,0.1499474618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.6315277235193186 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[27,47,63,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[27,47,63,108],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[4.916336653323167,2.646676038886771,2.4369873077900626]  |[0.4916336653323167,0.2646676038886771,0.24369873077900625]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.4916336653323167 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[29,48,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[29,48,58,101],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[6.315277235193186,2.185248146275699,1.499474618531115]   |[0.6315277235193186,0.21852481462756992,0.1499474618531115]  |0.0       |Iris-setosa    |0.6315277235193186 |
|Iris-setosa|(123,[33,35,96,110],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|0.0         |(123,[33,35,96,110],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|[2.6034320984484296,4.194443583750028,3.2021243178015424] |[0.26034320984484294,0.41944435837500277,0.32021243178015424]|1.0       |Iris-versicolor|0.26034320984484294|
+-----------+--------------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------+-------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Please observe the function to access feature vector, change the index as required starting from 0-

```
accessing first element from probability vector-
get_json_object(to_json(struct(probability)), '$.probability.values[0]')
accessing second element from probability vector
get_json_object(to_json(struct(probability)), '$.probability.values[1]')
```

Comment: for denseVector like this, you can just cast the Vector into StringType and then use from_json to convert string into an ArrayType column.

Comment: Yes agreed, there can be multiple alternatives to achieve this. If you like my answer, please upvote

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to split the probability columns generated after training a PySpark ML model into usable columns, you can split like this:

```
prob_df1=lr_pred.withColumn("probability",lr_pred["probability"].cast("String"))
prob_df = prob_df1.withColumn('probabilityre',split(regexp_replace("probability", "^\[|\]", ""), ",")[1].cast(DoubleType()))
```