# Pyspark Logistic Regression, accessing probabilities

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have the result from a `pyspark.ml.classificaton.LogisticRegression` model. One of the columns is `probability` which contains the following vector:

[image: Probabilities column]

I want to extract the value with the indices 3 and 1 and have written the following crude UDF but it keeps returning an index error even on valid records.

```
def getPurchProb(o):
  try: 
    return o[3][1]
  except ValueError:
    return -1.0
  except IndexError:
    return -2.0


udfPurchProb = udf(getPurchProb, DoubleType())
result.select(udfPurchProb("probability"))
```

What do I do wrong?

**Update**

This issue was flagged as a duplicate of [How to access element of a VectorUDT column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555864/how-to-access-element-of-a-vectorudt-column-in-a-spark-dataframe). I tried that approach before the one above hand had identical errors. My issue is that I experience and IndexError when trying to extract the value, not a ValueError on conversion.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate, as I actually tried that method first and with the same result.

Comment: It is a duplicate (or non-existing problem). You are existing a non-existent entry. I have not sure how you came up with `o[3][1]` (misinterpreted Databricks UI and off-by-one?) but what you want is `o[0]` or `o[1]`. There is no place for nesting here.