# pyspark - Convert sparse vector obtained after one hot encoding into columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, one-hot-encoding

I am using apache Spark ML lib to handle categorical features using one hot encoding. After writing the below code I am getting a vector `c_idx_vec` as output of one hot encoding. I do understand how to interpret this output vector but I am unable to figure out how to convert this vector into columns so that I get a new transformed dataframe.Take this dataset for example:

```py
>>> fd = spark.createDataFrame( [(1.0, "a"), (1.5, "a"), (10.0, "b"), (3.2, "c")], ["x","c"])
>>> ss = StringIndexer(inputCol="c",outputCol="c_idx")
>>> ff = ss.fit(fd).transform(fd)
>>> ff.show()

    +----+---+-----+
    |   x|  c|c_idx|
    +----+---+-----+
    | 1.0|  a|  0.0|
    | 1.5|  a|  0.0|
    |10.0|  b|  1.0|
    | 3.2|  c|  2.0|
    +----+---+-----+
```

By default, the OneHotEncoder will drop the last category:

```py
>>> oe = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="c_idx",outputCol="c_idx_vec")
>>> fe = oe.transform(ff)
>>> fe.show()
    +----+---+-----+-------------+
    |   x|  c|c_idx|    c_idx_vec|
    +----+---+-----+-------------+
    | 1.0|  a|  0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
    | 1.5|  a|  0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
    |10.0|  b|  1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
    | 3.2|  c|  2.0|    (2,[],[])|
    +----+---+-----+-------------+
```

Of course, this behavior can be changed:

```py
>>> oe.setDropLast(False)
>>> fl = oe.transform(ff)
>>> fl.show()

    +----+---+-----+-------------+
    |   x|  c|c_idx|    c_idx_vec|
    +----+---+-----+-------------+
    | 1.0|  a|  0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
    | 1.5|  a|  0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
    |10.0|  b|  1.0|(3,[1],[1.0])|
    | 3.2|  c|  2.0|(3,[2],[1.0])|
    +----+---+-----+-------------+
```

So, I wanted to know how to convert my `c_idx_vec` vector into new dataframe as below:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your question is, and give also an example of your required result

Comment: @desertnaut I have added my expected output. Please find link to see the output format for new dataframe after one hot encoding. This is similar to dataframe we obtain using get dummies in pandas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
>>> from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder, StringIndexer
>>>
>>> fd = spark.createDataFrame( [(1.0, "a"), (1.5, "a"), (10.0, "b"), (3.2, "c")], ["x","c"])
>>> ss = StringIndexer(inputCol="c",outputCol="c_idx")
>>> ff = ss.fit(fd).transform(fd)
>>> ff.show()
+----+---+-----+
|   x|  c|c_idx|
+----+---+-----+
| 1.0|  a|  0.0|
| 1.5|  a|  0.0|
|10.0|  b|  1.0|
| 3.2|  c|  2.0|
+----+---+-----+

>>>
>>> oe = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="c_idx",outputCol="c_idx_vec")
>>> oe.setDropLast(False)
OneHotEncoder_49e58b281387d8dc0c6b
>>> fl = oe.transform(ff)
>>> fl.show()
+----+---+-----+-------------+
|   x|  c|c_idx|    c_idx_vec|
+----+---+-----+-------------+
| 1.0|  a|  0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
| 1.5|  a|  0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])|
|10.0|  b|  1.0|(3,[1],[1.0])|
| 3.2|  c|  2.0|(3,[2],[1.0])|
+----+---+-----+-------------+

// Get c and its repective index. One hot encoder will put those on same index in vector

>>> colIdx = fl.select("c","c_idx").distinct().rdd.collectAsMap()
>>> colIdx
{'c': 2.0, 'b': 1.0, 'a': 0.0}
>>>
>>> colIdx =  sorted((value, "ls_" + key) for (key, value) in colIdx.items())
>>> colIdx
[(0.0, 'ls_a'), (1.0, 'ls_b'), (2.0, 'ls_c')]
>>>
>>> newCols = list(map(lambda x: x[1], colIdx))
>>> actualCol = fl.columns
>>> actualCol
['x', 'c', 'c_idx', 'c_idx_vec']
>>> allColNames = actualCol + newCols
>>> allColNames
['x', 'c', 'c_idx', 'c_idx_vec', 'ls_a', 'ls_b', 'ls_c']
>>>
>>> def extract(row):
...     return tuple(map(lambda x: row[x], row.__fields__)) + tuple(row.c_idx_vec.toArray().tolist())
...
>>> result = fl.rdd.map(extract).toDF(allColNames)
>>> result.show(20, False)
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+
|x   |c  |c_idx|c_idx_vec    |ls_a|ls_b|ls_c|
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+
|1.0 |a  |0.0  |(3,[0],[1.0])|1.0 |0.0 |0.0 |
|1.5 |a  |0.0  |(3,[0],[1.0])|1.0 |0.0 |0.0 |
|10.0|b  |1.0  |(3,[1],[1.0])|0.0 |1.0 |0.0 |
|3.2 |c  |2.0  |(3,[2],[1.0])|0.0 |0.0 |1.0 |
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+

// Typecast new columns to int

>>> for col in newCols:
...     result = result.withColumn(col, result[col].cast("int"))
...
>>> result.show(20, False)
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+
|x   |c  |c_idx|c_idx_vec    |ls_a|ls_b|ls_c|
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+
|1.0 |a  |0.0  |(3,[0],[1.0])|1   |0   |0   |
|1.5 |a  |0.0  |(3,[0],[1.0])|1   |0   |0   |
|10.0|b  |1.0  |(3,[1],[1.0])|0   |1   |0   |
|3.2 |c  |2.0  |(3,[2],[1.0])|0   |0   |1   |
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Converting a dataframe to RDD (in order to perform `map` operations) is in general not advisable, and it should be avoided except when absolutely necessary

Comment: Please, try to be constructive and not ironic (irony was certainly not the spirit of my reply to your comment)...

Comment: willing to mutually upvote, if you agree ;) (OP has too little reputation to do so, even if he accepts one of our answers)

Comment: Thanks @hadooper, This is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure it is the most efficient or simple way, but you can do it with a udf; starting from your `fl` dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, udf

def ith_(v, i):
    try:
        return float(v[i])
    except ValueError:
        return None

ith = udf(ith_, DoubleType())

(fl.withColumn('is_a', ith("c_idx_vec", lit(0)))
   .withColumn('is_b', ith("c_idx_vec", lit(1)))
   .withColumn('is_c', ith("c_idx_vec", lit(2))).show())
```

The result is:

```py
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+
|   x|  c|c_idx|    c_idx_vec|is_a|is_b|is_c|   
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+
| 1.0|  a|  0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])| 1.0| 0.0| 0.0|
| 1.5|  a|  0.0|(3,[0],[1.0])| 1.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|10.0|  b|  1.0|(3,[1],[1.0])| 0.0| 1.0| 0.0|
| 3.2|  c|  2.0|(3,[2],[1.0])| 0.0| 0.0| 1.0| 
+----+---+-----+-------------+----+----+----+
```

i.e. exactly as requested.

HT (and +1) to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555864/how-to-access-element-of-a-vectorudt-column-in-a-spark-dataframe) that provided the udf.

Comment: This is making assumption that vector length will always be of length 3

Comment: Thanks@desertnaut

Comment: @hadooper me too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the situation is specified to the case that `StringIndexer` was used to generate the index number, and then One-hot encoding is generated using `OneHotEncoderEstimator`. The entire code from end to end should be like:

1. Generate the data and index the string values, with the `StringIndexerModel` object is "saved"

```py
>>> fd = spark.createDataFrame( [(1.0, "a"), (1.5, "a"), (10.0, "b"), (3.2, "c")], ["x","c"])
>>> ss = StringIndexer(inputCol="c",outputCol="c_idx")
>>>
>>> # need to save the indexer model object for indexing label info to be used later
>>> ss_fit = ss.fit(fd)
>>> ss_fit.labels   # to be used later
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> ff = ss_fit.transform(fd)
>>> ff.show()

    +----+---+-----+
    |   x|  c|c_idx|
    +----+---+-----+
    | 1.0|  a|  0.0|
    | 1.5|  a|  0.0|
    |10.0|  b|  1.0|
    | 3.2|  c|  2.0|
    +----+---+-----+
```

2. Do one-hot encoding using `OneHotEncoderEstimator` class, since `OneHotEncoder` is [deprecating](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder)

```py
>>> oe = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=["c_idx"],outputCols=["c_idx_vec"])
>>> oe_fit = oe.fit(ff)
>>> fe = oe_fit.transform(ff)
>>> fe.show()
    +----+---+-----+-------------+
    |   x|  c|c_idx|    c_idx_vec|
    +----+---+-----+-------------+
    | 1.0|  a|  0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
    | 1.5|  a|  0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|
    |10.0|  b|  1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|
    | 3.2|  c|  2.0|    (2,[],[])|
    +----+---+-----+-------------+
```

3. Perform one-hot binary value reshaping. The one-hot values will always be `0.0` or `1.0`.

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.types dimport FloatType, IntegerType
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, udf

>>> ith = udf(lambda v, i: float(v[i]), FloatType())
>>> fx = fe
>>> for sidx, oe_col in zip([ss_fit], oe.getOutputCols()):
... 
...     # iterate over string values and ignore the last one
...     for ii, val in list(enumerate(sidx.labels))[:-1]:
...         fx = fx.withColumn(
...             sidx.getInputCol() + '_' + val, 
...             ith(oe_col, lit(ii)).astype(IntegerType())
...         )
>>> fx.show()
+----+---+-----+-------------+---+---+
|   x|  c|c_idx|    c_idx_vec|c_a|c_b|
+----+---+-----+-------------+---+---+
| 1.0|  a|  0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|  1|  0|
| 1.5|  a|  0.0|(2,[0],[1.0])|  1|  0|
|10.0|  b|  1.0|(2,[1],[1.0])|  0|  1|
| 3.2|  c|  2.0|    (2,[],[])|  0|  0|
+----+---+-----+-------------+---+---+
```

To be noticed that Spark, by default, removes the last category. So, following the behavior, the `c_c` column is not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to access sparse vector with data frame and i converted it to rdd.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

# column names
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c']
extract_f = lambda row: Row(**row.asDict(), **dict(zip(labels, row.c_idx_vec.toArray())))
fe.rdd.map(extract_f).collect()
```