# Most efficient way to one-hot encode using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I want to one-hot encode multiple categorical features using `pyspark` (version 2.3.2). My data is very large (hundreds of features, millions of rows). The problem is that pyspark's `OneHotEncoder` class returns its result as one vector column. I need to have the result as a separate column per category. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

**Option 1 & 2**

If you indeed use `OneHotEncoder`, the problem is how to transform that one vector column to separate binary columns. When searching around, I find that most other answers seem to use some variant of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark) which gives two options, both of which look very inefficient:

1. Use a `udf`. But I would like to avoid that since udf's are inherently inefficient, especially if I have to repeatedly use one for every categorical feature I want to one-hot encode.
2. Convert to `rdd`. Then for each row extract all the values and append the one-hot encoded features. You can find a good example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931269/pyspark-convert-sparse-vector-obtained-after-one-hot-encoding-into-columns):

```
def extract(row):
    return tuple(map(lambda x: row[x], row.__fields__)) + tuple(row.c_idx_vec.toArray().tolist())

result = df.rdd.map(extract).toDF(allColNames)
```

The problem is that this will extract each value for each row and then convert that back into a dataframe. This sounds horrible if you need to do this for a dataframe with hundreds of features and millions of rows, especially if you need to do it dozens of times.

Is there another, more efficient way to convert a vector column to separate columns that I'm missing? If not maybe it's better not to use `OneHotEncoder` at all, since I can't use the result efficiently. Which leads me to option 3.

**Option 3**

Option 3 would be to just one-hot encode myself using `reduce` statements and `withColumn`. For example:

```
df = reduce(
    lambda df, category: df.withColumn(category, sf.when(col('categoricalFeature') == category, sf.lit(1)))
    categories,
    df
)
```

Where `categories` is of course the list of possible categories in the feature `categoricalFeature`.

Before I spend hours/days implementing this, waiting for the results, debugging, etc. I wanted to ask if anyone has any experience with this? Is there an efficient way I'm missing? If not which of the three would probably be fastest?

Comment: Why don't you do `F.explode` on the vector column?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `explode` only splits an array into rows, not columns?

Comment: Try this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark

Comment: I already refer to that answer in my question including the reasons why I'm sceptical of implementing it for a huge dataframe. If these truly are the only options I might not even use `OneHotEncoder` and look for a more efficient way. The point of this question is to ask which of all these options is likely to be most efficient.