# PySpark Foreach

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using spark ml and would like to get the probability value calculated from a model in the probability column of a  DataFrame.

This works :

```
proba_classe_0 = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.probability[0])
```

But it gives me back an rdd.
I know ml was rdd based, and mllib is now df-based. 
I tried to use foreach :

```
df2.foreach(lambda r: r.probability[0])
```

But It gives back nothing.

I have Two questions :

1. How to make the foreach work ? I can't figure out
2. Ultimately I am trying to use BinaryClassificationMetrics
   as we can see here : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=binaryclassificationmetrics#pyspark.mllib.evaluation.BinaryClassificationMetrics . 
   As I can do the two needed values, how can I zip them to get them back together as a DF ?

Code:

```
proba_classe_1 = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.probability[1])
truth          = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.label         )
spark.createDataFrame(proba_classe_0)
```

> ```
> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'numpy.float64'>
> ```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: [How to access element of a VectorUDT column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555864/how-to-access-element-of-a-vectorudt-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Comment: @pault : nice catch ! could solve my problem. but still doesn't let me know what about the foreach :-/

Comment: *[`foreach`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach) is a shorthand for `df.rdd.foreach()`*

Comment: Now I have a strange : StructType can not accept object 0.6196931452705625 in type <class 'float'> : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753710/pyspark-cant-convert-float-to-float