# How to process Vector of probability with UDF in Pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a column with vectors like:

```
{"vectorType": "dense", "length": 7, "values": [0.6514390482520993, 0.195419935311166, 0.07402558401796841, 0.032660728394633604, 0.01775634445896352, 0.009769471437190208, 0.018928888127979045]}
```

and I would like to create a UDF function to process this probabilities like so:

```py
@udf("integer")
def process_probability(x):
  vector_values = x['values']
  if vector_values[0] > 0.65: return 0
  elif vector_values[1] > 0.198: return 1
  elif vector_values[2] > 0.08: return 2
  elif vector_values[3] > 0.035: return 3
  elif vector_values[4] > 0.045: return 4
  elif vector_values[5] > 0.00976: return 5
  elif vector_values[6] > 0.0188: return 6
```

but when I apply this I get the following error:

```py
>> processed_predictions = predictions.withColumn('processed_prediction', process_probability(predictions.probability))

File "<command-8587444>", line 3, in process_probability
  File "/spark/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 394, in __getitem__
    return self.array[item]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I have to use `.item` to access parts of a vector
like so:

```py
@udf("integer")
def process_probability(x):
  vector_values = x.values
  if vector_values.item(0) > 0.65: return 0
  elif vector_values.item(1) > 0.198: return 1
  elif vector_values.item(2) > 0.08: return 2
  elif vector_values.item(3) > 0.035: return 3
  elif vector_values.item(4) > 0.045: return 4
  elif vector_values.item(5) > 0.00976: return 5
  elif vector_values.item(6) > 0.0188: return 6
```

from here: [How to access element of a VectorUDT column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555864/how-to-access-element-of-a-vectorudt-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)