# Extract columns from an arrayish type of a vector column in databricks with pyspark

Tags: arrays, pyspark, vector, databricks, expand

Has anyone an idea how to retrieve from the probability column the first value "0" (which indicates the probability of that prediction being correct)

After running dataframe.schema (or dataframe.printSchema()) I got the following result for the probability column:

```
StructField('probability', VectorUDT(), True)
```

Below I am attaching part of the image of the dataframe.
[image]

I tried to expand the column probability with `col("probability.*")` but it gave me an error:

```
Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(probability)`.
```

I also tried to expand by just calling "probability.vectorType", for example! but I got the following error:

```
[INVALID_EXTRACT_BASE_FIELD_TYPE] Cannot extract a value from "probability". Need a complex type [STRUCT, ARRAY, MAP] but got "STRUCT, values: ARRAY>".
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access element of a VectorUDT column in a Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555864/how-to-access-element-of-a-vectorudt-column-in-a-spark-dataframe)

Comment: @Ronak Jain, thanks for your guidance. The answer marked as the "best one" did not help me much, but the answer from @Nidhi / n1tk solved the problem very clean.
.
.

`prob_df1=lr_pred.withColumn("probability",lr_pred["probability"].cast("String"))`
.
.

`prob_df =prob_df1.withColumn('probabilityre',split(regexp_replace("probability", "^\[|\]", ""), ",")[1].cast(DoubleType()))`