# Convert dense vector dataframe to individual columns in new dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, vector, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-conversion

I would like to convert a DenseVector based dataframe with a single column into a new dataframe with each item in the vector in its own column using pyspark. I do not want the output to be a vector.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'a'), (2, 'a'),
    (3, 'b'), (4, 'b'),
    (5, 'c'), (6, 'c'),
    (7, 'd'), (8, 'd'),
], schema=['value', 'name'])

xf = df.select(df["name"].alias("nam"), df["value"].alias("val"))
pf = df.join(xf, df["name"] == xf["nam"], "inner").where(xf["val"] < df["value"]).select(df["value"], xf["val"], df["name"])

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['value', "val"], outputCol="features")
selected_features = assembler.transform(pf).select('features')
selected_features.collect()
selected_features.show()
```

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark)