# How to use correlation in Spark with Dataframes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, correlation

Spark 2.2.0 [adds](http://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-2-0.html) correlation support for data-frames.
More information about that can be found in the [pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17108/files).

> MLlib
>       New algorithms in DataFrame-based API:
>
> > SPARK-19636: Correlation in DataFrame-based API (Scala/Java/Python)

Yet, it is entirely unclear how to use this change or what have changed comparing to previous version.

I expected something like:

```
df_num = spark.read.parquet('/dataframe')
df_cat.printSchema()
df_cat.show()
df_num.corr(col1='features', col2='fail_mode_meas')
```

```
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- fail_mode_meas: double (nullable = true)


+--------------------+--------------+
|            features|fail_mode_meas|
+--------------------+--------------+
|[0.0,0.5,0.0,0.0,...|          22.7|
|[0.9,0.0,0.7,0.0,...|           0.1|
|[0.0,5.1,1.0,0.0,...|           2.0|
|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|           3.1|
|[0.1,0.0,0.0,1.7,...|           0.0|
...

pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Currently correlation calculation for columns with dataType org.apach
e.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT not supported.'
```

Can someone explain how to take advantage of the new Spark 2.2.0 feature for correlation in dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method that can be used directly to achieve what you want. Python wrappers for the method implemented in SPARK-19636 are present in `pyspark.ml.stat`:

```
from pyspark.ml.stat import Correlation

Correlation.corr(df_cat, "features")
```

but this method is used to compute correlation matrix for *a single `Vector` column*.

You could:

- Assemble `features` and `fail_mode_meas` using `VectorAssembler` and apply `pyspark.ml.stat.Correlation` afterwards, but it will compute a number of obsolete values.
- [Expand vector column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38384347/6910411) and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.corr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.corr) but it will be expensive for large number of columns and add significant overhead when used with Python `udf`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Assembling feature vector together with another column for correlation is the best choice. Even with overhead it is faster than converting DF to pandas. Expanding vector column on the other hand is terribly slow.

Comment: @yauheni_selivonchyk -  Can you please post what you did to achieve that. it will be great help. Thanks. Basically "Assemble features and fail_mode_meas using VectorAssembler" - this Part.

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`features`' given input columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get correlation between all variables-

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
corr_mat=Statistics.corr(features, method="pearson")
```

Available from Spark 2.2.0