# Normalize column with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml, normalize

I have a data file with three columns, and I want to normalize the last column to apply ALS with ML (Spark and Scala), how can I do it?

Here is an excerpt from my `Dataframe`:

```
val view_df = spark.createDataFrame(view_RDD, viewSchema)
val viewdd = view_df.withColumn("userIdTemp", view_df("userId").cast(IntegerType)).drop("userId")
                    .withColumnRenamed("userIdTemp", "userId")
                    .withColumn("productIdTemp", view_df("productId").cast(IntegerType)).drop("productId")
                    .withColumnRenamed("productIdTemp", "productId")
                    .withColumn("viewTemp", view_df("view").cast(FloatType)).drop("view")
                    .withColumnRenamed("viewTemp", "view")`
```

Comment: [Feature normalization algorithm in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34234817/6910411)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [`StandardScaler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#standardscaler) is usually what you want to do when there is any scaling/normalization to be done. However, in this case there is only a single column to scale and it's not of `Vector` type (but `Float`). Since the `StandardScaler` only works on `Vectors`,  a [`VectorAssembler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) can be applied first, but then the `Vector` needs to be reconverted into a `Float` after the scaling.

The simpler way in this case would be to do it yourself. First get the mean and standard deviation of the column and then perform the scaling. It can be done on the `view` column as follows:

```
val (mean_view, std_view) = viewdd.select(mean("view"), stddev("view"))
  .as[(Double, Double)]
  .first()
viewdd.withColumn("view_scaled", ($"view" - mean_view) / std_view)
```

Comment: How can I do the same in Python ? (specifically the $"view" part)

Comment: @Simon30: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624129/how-to-standardize-one-column-in-spark-using-standardscaler