# Extract words from a string column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

i have a dataframe which contains many rows and columns. I want to extract words from the one columns  in separate columns .

existing Dataframe

```
|               title|          sale_price|      condition_id|

|"Lenovo ThinkPad ...|              599.00|        1500|
|ASUS ROG GL752VW-...|              999.99|        2000|
|Lenovo IdeaPad S1...|               71.00|        3000|
|Lenovo T520 i5 2....|              210.00|        2500|
|"Dell Inspiron 15...|              508.72|        1000|
|7 Apple Macbook P...|              446.00|        7000|
|Dell Latitude E64...|               41.00|        3000|
```

i want to split

```
**brand column**  :         **model**    :     **model_num** :      **other**


lenovo  :                   thinkpad  :       4500U  :          8GB RAM 256GB

dell          :             inspiron   :     GL752VW

hp:

dell       :                latitude:
```

is there any method to get my required data in pyspark datafram

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark)

Comment: is the format of column "title" same for all rows?

Comment: yes, the format of 'title' is same for all row