# RuntimeError: Unsupported type in conversion to Arrow: VectorUDT

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, pyarrow

I want to convert a big spark data frame to Pandas with more than 1000000 rows. I tried to convert a spark data Frame to Pandas data frame using the following code:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
result.toPandas()
```

But, I got the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   1949                 import pyarrow
-> 1950                 to_arrow_schema(self.schema)
   1951                 tables = self._collectAsArrow()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in to_arrow_schema(schema)
   1650     fields = [pa.field(field.name, to_arrow_type(field.dataType), nullable=field.nullable)
-> 1651               for field in schema]
   1652     return pa.schema(fields)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1650     fields = [pa.field(field.name, to_arrow_type(field.dataType), nullable=field.nullable)
-> 1651               for field in schema]
   1652     return pa.schema(fields)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in to_arrow_type(dt)
   1641     else:
-> 1642         raise TypeError("Unsupported type in conversion to Arrow: " + str(dt))
   1643     return arrow_type

TypeError: Unsupported type in conversion to Arrow: VectorUDT

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-4e12457ff4d5> in <module>()
      1 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
----> 2 result.toPandas()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   1962                     "'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' is set to true. Please set it to false "
   1963                     "to disable this.")
-> 1964                 raise RuntimeError("%s\n%s" % (_exception_message(e), msg))
   1965         else:
   1966             pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)

RuntimeError: Unsupported type in conversion to Arrow: VectorUDT
Note: toPandas attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled' is set to true. Please set it to false to disable this.
```

It's not working, but if I set arrow to false, it works. But It's so slow... Any idea?

Comment: Please share 1) sample of your data. 2) Output of df.printSchema()

Answer (score 6):

Arrow supports only a small set of types, and Spark `UserDefinedTypes`, including `ml` and `mllib` `VectorUDTs` are not among supported ones.

If you rally want to use arrow you'll have to convert your data to a format that it is supported. One possible solution is to expand `Vectors` into columns - [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38384347/8371915)

You can also serialize output using `to_json` method:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json

 df.withColumn("your_vector_column", to_json("your_vector_column"))
```

but if data is large enough for `toPandas` to be a serious bottleneck, then I would reconsider collecting data like this.