# Pyspark correlation with one hot encoding column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, correlation, one-hot-encoding

I am new in pyspark.
I want to count the correlation between a `column(int)` with another `column(vector from onehotencoder)`.
I use this code:

```
import six
for i in df.columns:
    if not(isinstance(df.select(i).take(1)[0][0], six.string_types)):
        print( "Correlation to label for", i, df.stat.corr('label',i))
```

I got this error when it counts the correlation between label a onehotencoder column:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o9219.corr. :
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    requirement failed:
      Currently correlation calculation for columns with dataType org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 not supported
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the error. Here is the error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o9219.corr.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Currently correlation calculation for columns with dataType org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 not supported.

Comment: Added it to the question for you :)

Comment: Do you have a minimal example to replicate? I guess you have to do an appropriate type cast in order to make the correlation work.

Comment: @pansen the column I tried to calculate the correlation is one hot encoder therefore it is a vector. To what type should I change its type?

Comment: Mmh, seems like you need to convert your vector column into regular numeric columns. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark?rq=1).