# pyspark extract ROC curve?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Is there a way to get the points on an ROC curve from Spark ML in pyspark? In the documentation I see an example for Scala but not python: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html

Is that right? I can certainly think of ways to implement it but I have to imagine it’s faster if there’s a pre-built function. I’m working with 3 million scores and a few dozen models so speed matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the ROC curve is a plot of FPR against TPR, you can extract the needed values as following:

```
your_model.summary.roc.select('FPR').collect()
your_model.summary.roc.select('TPR').collect())
```

Where `your_model` could be for example a model you got from something like this:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
log_reg = LogisticRegression()
your_model = log_reg.fit(df)
```

Now you should just plot FPR against TPR, using for example `matplotlib`.

**P.S.**

Here is a complete example for plotting ROC curve using a model named `your_model` (and anything else!). I've also plot a reference "random guess" line inside the ROC plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'r--')
plt.plot(your_model.summary.roc.select('FPR').collect(),
         your_model.summary.roc.select('TPR').collect())
plt.xlabel('FPR')
plt.ylabel('TPR')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. In my case though, I don't have the actual model. I have a two column rdd with probabilities and a binary label. In the scala docs, you can do `metrics = BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabels)` and then `metrics.roc` gives you the points. But that doesn't work for pyspark. I guess this is a hail mary that the function exists somewhere else?

Comment: Also, I am able to get _some_ of the model objects and reload them, with `from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegressionModel` and then `mdl = LogisticRegressionModel.load(loc)` but when I try your call I get `RuntimeError: No training summary available for this LogisticRegressionModel`. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Did you "fit" the model before loading it? The summary should be there as soon as you have trained the model. If you run `mdl.hasSummary` what happens? I have another guess regarding pipelines: if you put that model as the last stage of a pipeline, you can access it with `mdl.stages[-1].summary` instead of `mdl.summary`.

Comment: it was a model trained in another program and then saved to s3 with `mdl.write().save(s3_path)`. I guess somehow it loses the summary. I guess I just need to go back to the other program and pull out the ROC points before I save the model, and then save them as json or whatever. That's not ideal, but I guess it's the best option. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I understand. Usually I don't use save/load, so I cannot be helpful for that aspect. I'm glad I helped you!

Comment: BTW This is ROC on model trained on train data, not test data ROC.

Answer (score 22):

For a more general solution that works for models besides Logistic Regression (like Decision Trees or Random Forest which lack a model summary) you can get the ROC curve using [BinaryClassificationMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.html#BinaryClassificationMetrics) from Spark MLlib.

Note that the PySpark version doesn't implement all of the methods that the [Scala version](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/BinaryClassificationMetrics.html) does, so you'll need to use the `.call(name)` function from [JavaModelWrapper](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/common.html). It also seems that py4j doesn't support parsing `scala.Tuple2` classes, so they have to be manually processed.

Example:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics

# Scala version implements .roc() and .pr()
# Python: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/common.html
# Scala: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/BinaryClassificationMetrics.html
class CurveMetrics(BinaryClassificationMetrics):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CurveMetrics, self).__init__(*args)

    def _to_list(self, rdd):
        points = []
        # Note this collect could be inefficient for large datasets 
        # considering there may be one probability per datapoint (at most)
        # The Scala version takes a numBins parameter, 
        # but it doesn't seem possible to pass this from Python to Java
        for row in rdd.collect():
            # Results are returned as type scala.Tuple2, 
            # which doesn't appear to have a py4j mapping
            points += [(float(row._1()), float(row._2()))]
        return points

    def get_curve(self, method):
        rdd = getattr(self._java_model, method)().toJavaRDD()
        return self._to_list(rdd)
```

Usage:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a Pipeline estimator and fit on train DF, predict on test DF
model = estimator.fit(train)
predictions = model.transform(test)

# Returns as a list (false positive rate, true positive rate)
preds = predictions.select('label','probability').rdd.map(lambda row: (float(row['probability'][1]), float(row['label'])))
points = CurveMetrics(preds).get_curve('roc')

plt.figure()
x_val = [x[0] for x in points]
y_val = [x[1] for x in points]
plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel(xlabel)
plt.ylabel(ylabel)
plt.plot(x_val, y_val)
```

[image: ROC curve generated with PySpark BinaryClassificationMetrics]

BinaryClassificationMetrics in Scala implements several other useful methods as well:

```py
metrics = CurveMetrics(preds)
metrics.get_curve('fMeasureByThreshold')
metrics.get_curve('precisionByThreshold')
metrics.get_curve('recallByThreshold')
```

Comment: this code gives an error 
NameError: name 'points' is not defined. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to replace points, with "roc", as you are creating the list here: `roc = CurveMetrics(preds).get_curve('roc')` and also replace the variable names in the plotting function.

Comment: Thanks @AlexRoss this really helped ! I wish i could up it multiple times !

Comment: Is there really no way to convert scala.Tuple2s without collecting the whole RDD? This has been driving me crazy all day

Comment: I spent a day looking into it as well back around the time of this answer, and didn't find a way. But I might have missed something or the API might have changed. Agreed not ideal for large datasets.

Comment: I tried this solution on Spark 3.1.2 and Azure Databricks however get exception `Exception ignored in: <function JavaModelWrapper.__del__ at 0x7f0118d35820>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 137, in __del__
    self._sc._gateway.detach(self._java_model)
AttributeError: 'CurveMetrics' object has no attribute '_sc'`. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 4):

To get ROC metrics for train data (trained model), we can use `your_model.summary.roc` which is a DataFrame with columns `FPR` and `TPR`. See Andrea's answer.

For ROC evaluated on arbitrary test data, we can use `label` and `probability` columns to pass to sklearn's `roc_curve` to get FPR and TPR. Here we assume a binary classification problem where the y score is the probability of predicting 1. See also [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark), [How to convert a pyspark dataframe column to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58162761/how-to-convert-a-pyspark-dataframe-column-to-numpy-array)

Example

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve

model = lr.fit(train_df)
test_df_predict = model.transform(test_df)

y_score = test_df_predict.select(vector_to_array("probability")[1]).rdd.keys().collect()
y_true = test_df_predict.select("label").rdd.keys().collect()
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_score)
```

Comment: Upvoting, as this answer highlights that `model.summary` is a training property - which some find confusing.