# How to convert a pyspark dataframe column to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a pyspark dataframe column having approximately 90 million rows into a numpy array.

I need the array as an input for `scipy.optimize.minimize` function.

I have tried both converting to Pandas and using `collect()`, but these methods are very time consuming.

I am new to PySpark, If there is a faster and better approach to do this, Please help.

Thanks

This is how my dataframe looks like.

```
+----------+
|Adolescent|
+----------+
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
|       0.0|
+----------+
```

Comment: Have you tried `df['Adolescent'].to_numpy()` or `df['Adolescent'].array`?

Comment: It looks like to_numpy() works for pandas data frame only and not pyspark. I tried df["Adolescent"].array which gives the output: "Column<b'Adolescent[array]'>". I don't know how to use this as array.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## #1

You will have to call a `.collect()` in any way. To create a numpy array from the pyspark dataframe, you can use:

```
adoles = np.array(df.select("Adolescent").collect()) #.reshape(-1) for 1-D array
```

## #2

You can convert it to a pandas dataframe using [toPandas()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas), and you can then convert it to numpy array using `.values`.

```
pdf = df.toPandas()
adoles = df["Adolescent"].values
```

Or simply:

`adoles = df.select("Adolescent").toPandas().values #.reshape(-1) for 1-D array`

## #3

For distributed arrays, you can try [Dask Arrays](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array.html)

I haven't tested this, but assuming it would work the same as numpy (might have inconsistencies):

```
import dask.array as da
adoles = da.array(df.select("Adolescent").collect()) #.reshape(-1) for 1-D array
```

Comment: I have tried using toPandas() but it is taking a lot of time.

Comment: You should have a look at [Dask Arrays](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am trying with dask arrays now.

Comment: np.concatenate(
        df.select("user_id").rdd.glom().map(
          lambda x: np.array([elem[0] for elem in x]))
        .collect())

https://medium.com/@karthik.jayaraman1/creating-a-scipy-sparse-matrix-from-a-spark-dataframe-using-glom-125a6d0c4fd

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to convert the selected column to RDD, then flatten by  extracting the value of each `Row` (can abuse `.keys()`), then convert to numpy array:

```
x = df.select("colname").rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()  # python list
np.array(x)  # numpy array
```