# Extract element from list pyspark

Tags: arrays, list, apache-spark, pyspark

[image]

Not able to extract the third element from the column features:

```
rescaledData.withColumn("test", rescaledData["features"].getItem(2))
rescaledData.selectExpr("features[2]").show()
```

Both don't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark)

Comment: That's not list, that's ML or MLlib vector.