# Convert PySpark DenseVector to array

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to convert a pyspark dataframe column of DenseVector into array but I always got an error.

```
data = [(Vectors.dense([8.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0]),),
(Vectors.dense([2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),),
(Vectors.dense([4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0]),)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["features"])
```

I tried to define a UDF and use toArray()

```
to_array = udf(lambda x: x.toArray(), ArrayType(FloatType()))
df = df.withColumn('features', to_array('features'))
```

But then, I got the following error if I do df.collect()

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times, 
most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 100, 10.139.64.6, executor 0): 
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict 
(for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)
```

Any idea on how I could achieve this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[toArray()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=vectors#pyspark.ml.linalg.Vectors) returns a numpy.ndarray which can't be converted to `ArrayType(FloatType())` implicitely. Use additionally `.tolist()` to convert it:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

#or: to_array = F.udf(lambda v: list([float(x) for x in v]), T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()))
to_array = F.udf(lambda v: v.toArray().tolist(), T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()))
df = df.withColumn('features', to_array('features'))
```

In case you are using Pyspark **>=3.0.0** you can use the new [vector_to_array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.functions.vector_to_array.html?highlight=vector_to#pyspark.ml.functions.vector_to_array) function:

```py
from pyspark.ml.functions import vector_to_array
df = df.withColumn('features', vector_to_array('features'))
```

Comment: @Sultan1991: I have added the imports

Comment: This answer has perhaps saved me from jumping off my balcony.

Comment: If you're using spark 3.0.0 then there's a fun available to do this: vector_to_array. More about it here in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385033/2650427).