# pyspark make new column with single Row element of other column?

Tags: pyspark

I trained a xgb classifier model in pyspark and transformed some data via

```
outp = model.transform(inp)
```

now outp contains a column 'probability' with row entries such as

```
Row(probability=DenseVector([0.99,0.01]))
```

I'd like to add a new column to outp, that contains rows of floats from the second probability component of the Row elements mentioned above (so e.g. just 0.01 instead of Row(...) ). What is the correct syntax to do that?

I tried

```
outp = outp.select("*",(col('probability')[:,1]).alias('prob'))
```

expecting that the first element of each row in the column will be selected. But that syntax produces an error.

Comment: convert `DenseVector` to `array` using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58495099/8279585), and then use `getItem()` column method to extract second element from the resulting array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion from the comment by samkart, I changed the syntax to:

```
outp = outp.select("*",(vector_to_array('probability').getItem(1)).alias('prob'))
```

and now it does what I wanted.