# How to convert a column of type Vector to array/string type in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider following dataframe in pyspark:

```
+-----------+
|      Col A|
+-----------+
| [0.5, 0.6]|                  
| [0.7, 0.8]|                   
| [1.1, 1.5]|                                 
+-----------+
```

The type of Col A is vector, how can I create a new column which has values of Col A but is of type array or string?

df:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|Col A      |new_column |
+-----------+-----------+
| [0.5, 0.6]|  0.5, 0.6 |               
| [0.7, 0.8]|  0.7, 0.8 |            
| [1.1, 1.5]|  1.1, 1.5 |                         
+-----------+-----------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert Vector into Array[Double] this is fairly simple with the UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
val toArr: Any => Array[Double] = _.asInstanceOf[DenseVector].toArray
val toArrUdf = udf(toArr)
val dataWithFeaturesArr = dataWithFeatures.withColumn("A_arr",toArrUdf('COl A'))
```

Comment: it complains about invalid syntax

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution could be:

```
scala> output.show
+---+---------+
| id|vectorCol|
+---+---------+
|  0|[1.2,1.3]|
|  1|[2.2,2.3]|
|  2|[3.2,3.3]|
+---+---------+


scala> output.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- vectorCol: vector (nullable = true)


scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector

scala> val toArr: Any => Array[Double] = _.asInstanceOf[DenseVector].toArray
toArr: Any => Array[Double] = <function1>

scala> val toArrUdf = udf(toArr)
toArrUdf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(DoubleType,false),None)

scala> val df1 = output.withColumn("features_arr",toArrUdf('vectorCol))

scala> df1.show
+---+---------+------------+
| id|vectorCol|features_arr|
+---+---------+------------+
|  0|[1.2,1.3]|  [1.2, 1.3]|
|  1|[2.2,2.3]|  [2.2, 2.3]|
|  2|[3.2,3.3]|  [3.2, 3.3]|
+---+---------+------------+

scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- vectorCol: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- features_arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

A possible implementation in pyspark could be seen in this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark)

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, the link for pysaprk they use vector_to_array function which doesn't work and I can't find any documentation for it..

Comment: @tia In the same link, there are other possible answers. Let me know if you are able to find for spark < 3.0.0