# How can I resolve the "need struct type but got struct"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

[image]

As you can see on my picture, I have a column named probability and I want to create a new column from the **probability** column. I want to extract values from the probability column which is an array. But while trying to do so, I receive an error:

`"Can't extract value from probability#52427: need struct type but got struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>"`

Here is my extraction code:

`preds_test = preds.withColumn("newCol", col("probability").getItem(3))`

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark)

Comment: while trying the first option I have this error **No module named 'pyspark.ml.functions'**

Answer (score -5):

I figured it out. I used a lambda function. This is my code:

````
preds_subset = preds.select('CustomerID','prediction', probs_churn('probability')).orderBy(asc("probability"))```
````

Comment: what is `probs_churn`?

Comment: forgot to show the `probs_churn` custom function?