# Create PySpark Dataframe from Features Vector with Label

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, vector, pyspark

I have a dataframe which I created with a Pipeline object that looks like this:

```
df.show()

+--------------------+-----+
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
|[-0.0775219322931...|    0|
+--------------------+-----+
```

I have successfully extracted the features vectors like this:

```
df_table = df.rdd.map(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x['features']]).toDF(cols)
```

The problem with the above is that it does not retain the label column. As a workaround, I used a Join successfully to bring that label column back but I find that it's too convoluted.

How would I use a one-liner such as the above to both extract the features vector and make a Spark DF out of it and at the same time append that label column to it as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have good options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark), especially if you have a version of `Spark` >= 3.0.0

Assuming you don't have such recent version, your problem comes from the fact that you loose your key in your map. You can do:

```py
df_table = df.rdd.map(lambda l: tuple([l['label']] + [float(y) for y in l['features']])).toDF()
```

You end-up with a wide formatted dataframe. If you want a long formatted vector, you have more options.

## If you want long-formatted data

First, with rdd:

```py
df.rdd.flatMapValues(lambda l: l).toDF(['label','feature'])
```

Or, even better, directly using `DataFrame API`: (untested solution)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df.select('label', psf.explode(psf.col('label')))
```

Comment: Wow. I was searching a lot for this solution.Simplified and works like a charm.Thanks.