# how to get elements from a probability Column prediction in a pyspark model

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can i to get the first element from the probability model results in a pyspark dataframe?

```
+------+--------------------+
|labelh|         probability|
+------+--------------------+
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.99989771872286...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|
|     1|[0.72498853530094...|    
+------+--------------------+
```

The probability column has two elements and is type "vector" variable. I need the first element from this column and paste it in the dataframe.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It works, thank you!!.
Question: why do you need to define a udf to make this operation?, I've seen this function, but i dont know how this works!!!

Comment: `Vector` is implemented as an `UserDefinedType` and there is just no function which can operate on that. There was an idea of [VectorDisasembler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41639236/8371915) but it has been rejected for now.