# Spark Dataset<Row> Vector column to Array type conversion

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a column "features" which is a vector. Is there a way to convert this Vector column to Array column? I am using Spark 2.3 and Java.
Actually, the final objective is to split the Vector into individual columns. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `UserDefinedFunction`. You can define one like this:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

UserDefinedFunction toarray = udf(
  (Vector v) -> v.toArray(),  new ArrayType(DataTypes.DoubleType, false)
);
```

and then apply it on a `Column`:

```java
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;

Column featutesArray = toarray.apply(col("features"));
```

where the result can be used with `select` or `withColumn`.

> the final objective is to split the Vector into individual columns.

That's just a matter of simple indexing - [Spark Scala: How to convert Dataframe[vector] to DataFrame[f1:Double, ..., fn: Double)]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38110038/10465355)